python mock patch call_args_list type
Looking into patch call_args_list feature, I have found something strange.
The execution of the code below, returns different types for the list call_args_list.kwargs with Python3.7 and python3.11 interpretes:

with Python 3.7 the type is <class 'unittest.mock._Call'>
while with python 3.11 the type is <class 'dict'>.

from unittest import mock

def foobar(foo = None, bar = None):
 print(f'args: {foo}, {bar}')

l = None
with mock.patch('__main__.foobar') as m:
 foobar(foo=1, bar=4)
 l = m.call_args_list

type(l[0].kwargs)

So I have 2 questions:

in the official documentation I can't find it where it was changed?

what's the proper way to work with the call args? Let's say I want to validate that the kwarg named foo was set to "bar" in the call to the mocked function (with dict is very easy, with _Call I don't have found a way to do so).



I hope that with this answer I can satisfy your second question; I suppose that is enough for you because the execution of the instruction type(l[0].kwargs) returns <class 'unittest.mock._Call'> also in my system, since I have execute the following code with Python 3.6.9 < Python 3.7 (as you can see in the output of the script execution).
from unittest import mock
import sys

def foobar(foo = None, bar = None):
    print(f'args: {foo}, {bar}')

l = None
with mock.patch('__main__.foobar') as m:
    foobar(foo=1, bar=4)
    l = m.call_args_list

print(sys.version)
print(type(l[0].kwargs))

for args, kwargs in l:
    for arg in args:
        print(f"arg = {arg}")
    for key in kwargs:
        print(f"Value of kwarg['{key}'] = {kwargs[key]}")

The output of the execution of the previous code is the following:
3.6.9 (default, Mar 10 2023, 16:46:00) 
[GCC 8.4.0]
<class 'unittest.mock._Call'>
Value of kwarg['foo'] = 1
Value of kwarg['bar'] = 4

kwargs is a dictionary although the type(l[0].kwargs) return <class 'unittest.mock._Call'>.

@eddie A feedback would be appreciated
